# How to rename files from a sorted list?

Tags: python, sorting, rename

I have a bunch of files that are numbered from 1-20 (Result 1.pdf, Result 2.pdf... etc.) and I'm trying to rename them with serial numbers included (Result 1 = Output 300, Result 2 = Output 301...).

When I try to rename 20 of these files, they get sorted as follows: Result 1, Result 10, Result 11 etc. I have some code that works to naturally sort these files and store the names in a list:

```
import natsort
from natsort import natsorted, ns

path = os.getcwd() + "/"
raw_list = [_ for _ in os.listdir(path) if _.endswith(".pdf")]
sorted_list = natsorted(raw_list, key = lambda y: y.lower())
```

When I print `sorted_list`, it returns a list of filenames that are sorted the way I want them (yay!).

I also have code that renames files using some information that the user inputs:

```
def rename():
    global i
    for filename in sorted_list:
        if ".pdf" in filename:
            my_dest = str(user_inp_1) + " " + str(user_inp_2).zfill(4) + ".pdf"
            my_source = path + filename
            my_dest = path + my_dest
            os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
            i = i + 1

    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "All files have been renamed successfully!")
```

This used to work on the non-sorted files, but I am not sure how to make it work on the sorted list. Is there something that I'm missing?

Edit: I showed the script to a coworker and we ended up rewriting the whole thing... I got rid of the global variables and other such non-pythonic things.

Comment: `_` commonly used as a name of variable you won't work with, do not use it for naming variables, which you're working with. There're some typos and indentation problems in your question, consider fixing them.

Comment: You need to provide a runnable [mre] (MRE) and explain what each of the global variables being used in the function are or do. You do know [Global Variables Are Bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad), right? You should pass them as arguments to the function and return any that were changed.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right and you need just to rename files like this:

Result 1.pdf -> Output 300.pdf
...
Result 20.pdf -> Output 319.pdf

I would parse the number as int a add 299.

```
from pathlib import Path
fpaths = Path().glob("Result*.pdf")

for f in fpaths:
    no = int(f.stem.rsplit(" ", 1)[-1])
    new_name = f"Output {no + 299}.pdf"
    print(f"rename {f} -> {new_name}")
    f.rename(new_name)  # comment this out for dry run
```